# Graph api- i can't get the invitation information about an shared item in the onedrive

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I succeed to get my sharing items but I have an item which is shared with a external user.

[image]

When I use this request: /me/drive/items/{item-id}/permissions

I have the list of internal user who the item is shared but I don't have any information about the external invitation that you can see inthe top of the picture.

I don't have the invition property like that :

```
{
  "id": "string (identifier)",
  "grantedTo": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identitySet"},
  "inheritedFrom": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.itemReference"},
  "invitation": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.sharingInvitation"},
  "link": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.sharingLink"},
  "roles": ["string"],
  "shareId": "string"
}
```

Do you have a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

[At this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40232274/2318967), an answer was done

> Other properties, like invitation and inheritedFrom are currently available for OneDrive Personal drives, but not available from OneDrive for Business or SharePoint document libraries.

Now using sharepoint library, i'm able to found all the permissions (including invitation and inheritedFrom. Maybe a workaround!

Try to use it to get the permisions!

I hope this help you!

Comment: how can i get those permission by using Graph API? Still stucked on SiteiD and WebUrl. is there any way to get those data from onedrive?